# Why does the general algorithm for proving surjectivity of a function seem to fail for $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$?

Tags: functions

Say I have a function $$f:\mathbb{R}^+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$
defined as $$f(x)=\sqrt{x}$$

Now, going by the standard procedure by taking some arbitrary element $\mathbf{y}\in{R}$ and solving to get some $\mathbf{x=g(y)}$, we end up with $x=y^2$. And then we see that for all $$\mathbf{y\in{R}},$$ $$\mathbf{x\in{R^+}}.$$ Thereby it seems that the function is $surjective.$
I understand that it is trivial to understand from definition that the function is not $onto$. So does that mean I have to check the initial conditions everytime I see a $surd$ in a function before proceeding as above, or am I missing something?

Comment: When you go from $y = \sqrt x$ to $y^2 = x$ you introduce values of $y$ such that the expression on the right is true and the expression on the left is not.  Squaring is not injective.

Comment: $\sqrt{x} = y$ is not solvable unless $y \ge 0$.

Comment: "and solving to get some x=g(y)"  What the heck is $g(y)$?  You don't know that any such function exists or is well defined.  You must solve for $\sqrt{x} = y$.  That means we must solve for $x =y^2; y \ge 0$ and... that's not possible if $y < 0$.

Comment: Yes, I understand now, thanks for the help. By "and solving to get some $x=g(y)$", I meant getting $x$ in terms of $y$, and checking whether for every $y$ there exists a pre-image or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surds don't have anything to do with the issue. Let's take a look at what you did: you fixed $y \in \mathbb{R}$ and tried to find $x \in \mathbb{R}^+$ such that $y = \sqrt{x}$. Then you squared both sides and obtained $y^2 = x$.

But since squaring is not injective, we have that $y^2 = x$ is a necessary condition for $y = \sqrt{x}$, but it is not sufficient. That's why right now you only know that any number $x$ that works (i.e. such that $y = \sqrt{x}$) must be equal to $y^2$, but you don't know if $y^2$ will work itself. To complete the argument, you have to check it manually by plugging in: is it true that $y = \sqrt{y^2}$? If you do, you'll see that it's not always true, namely - it fails for negative $y$.

So in general, when you solve an equation, such as $f(x) = y$, and **conclude** from the equation that $x \in X$ for some set $X$ - i.e. if you prove that for all $x, y$ we have that

$$y = f(x) \implies x \in X$$

- then you still have to check which elements of $X$ actually satisfy the equation.

You don't have to do that if all the transformations you make are equivalences, i.e. if you prove that for all $x, y$ we have that

$$y = f(x) \iff x \in X,$$

then you can immediately tell that $X$ is the solution set. Of course in your specific case $X = \{ y^2 \}$.